# Character Movement in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

So, in my game I have created several platforms that randomly spawn and move upwards, the aim of the game is for the player to constantly be moving down, and avoid reaching the top, I have the left and right movement working fine, and I have a boolean called hittingPlatform which is false, and in a loop event I move the player down if hittingPlatform is equal to true.

However, when the player does hit it, I set it to true, in the loop event make him move upwards with the platform, my problem is that when he goes back off the platform, I need to set it to false. I tried using an else statement in the collision detection but that didn't work, and I don't know what else to do, any suggestions? If it doesn't make sense/isn't clear enough please do tell me!

```
var player:Player = new Player();
var platformOne:PlatformOne = new PlatformOne();  
var platformTwo:PlatformTwo = new PlatformTwo();
var hittingPlatform:Boolean = false;    

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loopEvent);
player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,playerCollision);

function playerCollision(event:Event):void{
    if(player.hitTestObject(platformOne)){
        hittingPlatform = true;
    }
    else if(player.hitTestObject(platformTwo)){
        hittingPlatform = true;
    }
}

function loopEvent(event:Event):void{
    if(!hittingPlatform){
        player.y -= 5;
    }
    else if(hittingPlatform){
        player.y += 5;
    }
}
```

So where the collisions are, I just need to make it that if the player moves off that specific platform, it sets back to false, I tried an else statement but that didn't work since there are several platforms, any help appreciated!

Comment: Hi Brent! Welcome to StackOverflow! While your question is certainly on topic for this site, take a look at the [help center - how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Normally questions that provide code and are reproducible receive the best answers. Could you provide an minimal, complete, verifiable code example to accompany your question?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I don't have the code on hand but I can re-produce it!

Answer (score 0):

```
var player: Player = new Player();
var platformOne: PlatformOne = new PlatformOne();
var platformTwo: PlatformTwo = new PlatformTwo();
var hittingPlatform: Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loopEvent);
player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playerCollision);

function playerCollision(event: Event): void {
  if (player.hitTestObject(platformOne) || player.hitTestObject(platformTwo)) {
    hittingPlatform = true;
  } else {
    hittingPlatform = false;
  }
}

function loopEvent(event: Event): void {
  if (!hittingPlatform) {
    player.y -= 5;
  } else if (hittingPlatform) {
    player.y += 5;
  }
}
```

How about you edit your code in this way so that whenever the player is hitting the platform, the hittingPlatform is set true and when not, it is set false.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I thought that with that or operator, it would mean that even if they hit platform one, hitting anything else would automatically set it to false, but re-reading it I just realized how it actually worked, I will test it and mark an answered if it works, thank you for the response!

Comment: Sure. If it doesn't work then let me know. It should work though. :)